# change values of variables

Tags: java, variables

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGoOt.png)

What is the flow of control for this program? How can the second System.out.println(bmi) use the second 'weight' values(180) not the first one(195). I am confused.

Thank you

Comment: Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to understand why you should not post images on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... pretty new don't worry.

First of all they define *three* `variables` with *data-type* `double`

Secondly, they initiated `weight` and `height` for the first time, at this moment both `weight` and `height` got values and `bmi` also gets calculated as per formula

And at last

when they said `weight = 180` they are basically changing values of `weight` *variable*, cause its a *variable* it can hold only one value at a time. So now **weight = 180**

> Also you asked when bmi not get `195` instead `180` reason is simple.
>   Codes execution run in series, so in general it start executing from
>   top to bottom

Comment: Thats very clear! Thats what I am confused of. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually variables are pointing to memory locations whose values can be changed within their scope. So when 180 is assigned to weight variable it overrides the previous value in memory and now it has 180 instead of 195 while calculating BMI second time. 
Simple example to understand

```
double val = 25;
System.out.println(val); //It will print 25
val = 80; //will override 25 and after the execution of this line val will have 80 not 25
System.out.println(val); //It will print 80
val = 60;  //changing again
System.out.println(val); //It will print 60
```

Every time you change the value of variable it's previous value gone and it will have latest value you assigned to it.

Comment: I see, so it excuse in order from top to the bottum. If I want the value to be 25 again, I just have to write 'val = 25' again, or delete the previous 'val = 80' and 'val = 60' .

Comment: if you want 25 again you need to assign val = 25 again after last print statement.